# React State is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, frontend, state

```
import React from 'react'

class Help extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      friend:[
        {
          name:"ashwani",
          id:"1",
          friend:[
            {
              name:"mayank",
              id:"2",
              friend:[
                {
                  name:"prakhar",
                  id:"3",
                  friend:[]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name:"anand",
              id:"4",
              friend:[]
            },
            {
              name:"manish",
              id:"5",
              friend:[]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.friend.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} {...item} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class Item extends React.Component {
  addFriend(friend){
    friend.push({name:"GOD",friend:[]});
    console.log(friend);
  }
  render() {
    const { name, friend } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div style={{margin: '5px 25px'}}>
          <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.addFriend(friend)}>add friend</button>
     strong text
          {friend && friend.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} {...item} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Help;
```

React state is not updating i know i have done in a wrong way but i don't have any idea how to do it so what i am trying is their is button which will add friend in nested friend array which ever friend required another friend that friend is God it can be added as many time as u click the button, button is for every friend array present so that they don't feel lonely and can add friend whenever they want , this is just a usecase in my project so, any kind of help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: where u are updating state ???  `this.setState()`

Comment: updating obj, will not rennder react componnet.. read react https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Storing your state in such a way makes it quite difficult to deal with, but it should be possible to make it work. Your problem is, that you are trying to mutate state, which isn't allowed in React. In order to update state you have to use `this.setState` and in your case, some extra complex code is needed:

```
import React from 'react'

class Help extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      friend:[
        {
          name:"ashwani",
          id:"1",
          friend:[
            {
              name:"mayank",
              id:"2",
              friend:[
                {
                  name:"prakhar",
                  id:"3",
                  friend:[]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name:"anand",
              id:"4",
              friend:[]
            },
            {
              name:"manish",
              id:"5",
              friend:[]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  updateFriends = (friendIndex) => (newFriendValue) => {
    this.setState(prevFriends => {
      let newFriends = Array.from(prevFriends);
      newFriends[friendIndex] = newFriendValue;

      return { friend: newFriends };
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.friend.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} {...item} updateFriends={this.updateFriends(index)} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class Item extends React.Component {
  addFriend(friend){
    let newFriends = [...this.props.friend, {name:"GOD",friend:[]}];

    this.props.updateFriends({ name: this.props.name, friend: newFriends })
  }

  updateFriends = (friendIndex) => (newFriendValue) => {
    let newFriends = Array.from(this.props.friend);
    newFriends[friendIndex] = newFriendValue;

    this.props.updateFriends({ name: this.props.name, friend: newFriends })
  }

  render() {
    const { name, friend } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div style={{margin: '5px 25px'}}>
          <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.addFriend(friend)}>add friend</button>
     strong text
          {friend && friend.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} {...item} updateFriends={this.updateFriends(index)} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Help;
```

Feel free to ask for any clarifications!

Comment: thanks a lot Adam ,i wish ,i can return your kindness oneday . I am so happy now.

Comment: I'm glad I made your day ^_^. You could return it by accepting the answer and giving an upvote :D hahaha

Answer (score -1):

State is not updating because you are not calling `this.setState();` to set the friends in the parent.